# ApexCharts forecastdatapoints not showing in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, charts, apexcharts

I have an Angular application where we want to use ForecastDataPoints like this:
https://apexcharts.com/angular-chart-demos/line-charts/gradient/

However, when you check the code in the demo above the ForecastDataPoints are not in there.

I downloaded a sample code, but it doesnt contain a demo for Angular.
I use ApexCharts 3.32.1 and ng-apexcharts 1.6.0 together with Angular 11.2.0.

Ts file:

```
this.chartOptions = {
      series: [{
      name: 'Sales',
      data: [4, 3, 10, 9, 29, 19, 22, 9, 12, 7, 19, 5, 13, 9, 17, 2, 7, 5]
    }],
      chart: {
      height: 350,
      type: 'line',
    },
    forecastDataPoints: {
      count: 7,
      dashArray:4,
      fillOpacity: 0.5
    },
    stroke: {
      width: 5,
      curve: 'smooth'
    },
    xaxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      categories: ['1/11/2000', '2/11/2000', '3/11/2000', '4/11/2000', '5/11/2000', '6/11/2000', '7/11/2000', '8/11/2000', '9/11/2000', '10/11/2000', '11/11/2000', '12/11/2000', '1/11/2001', '2/11/2001', '3/11/2001','4/11/2001' ,'5/11/2001' ,'6/11/2001'],
      tickAmount: 10,
      labels: {
        formatter: function(value, timestamp, opts) {
          return opts.dateFormatter(new Date(timestamp), 'dd MMM')
        }
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Forecast',
      align: 'left',
      style: {
        fontSize: "16px",
        color: '#666'
      }
    },
    fill: {
      type: 'gradient',
      gradient: {
        shade: 'dark',
        gradientToColors: [ '#FDD835'],
        shadeIntensity: 1,
        type: 'horizontal',
        opacityFrom: 1,
        opacityTo: 1,
        stops: [0, 100, 100, 100]
      },
    },
    yaxis: {
      min: -10,
      max: 40
    }
  };
```

Html file:

```
<apx-chart
                [series]="chartOptions.series"
                [chart]="chartOptions.chart"
                [foreCastDataPoints]="chartOptions.forecastDataPoints"
                [xaxis]="chartOptions.xaxis"
                [dataLabels]="chartOptions.dataLabels"
                [grid]="chartOptions.grid"
                [stroke]="chartOptions.stroke"
                [title]="chartOptions.title"
                [markers]="chartOptions.markers"
                [yaxis]="chartOptions.yaxis"
                [fill]="chartOptions.fill"
            ></apx-chart>
```

I got no errors in my console. Everything is working except the forecast points.